# how to display checked values in checkbox using angular array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've already accomplished selecting htc in home page and coming to another page.  Now I want to display whether the selected store value and severdata match (in this case I need to show true).  During the on submit event, I want to pass all selected values.   I have tried the code below, but its not working for me.

```
$scope.Selctedstores =window.localStorage.getItem("selectedservices");
console.log($scope.Selctedstores);
//console i am getting htc

var serverData = ["Nokia", "Htc", "Samsung"];       
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++)
    {
        var modal = {
            name: serverData[i],
            selected: false
        };           
        $scope.items.push(modal);
    }
    $scope.check = function()
    {
        var checkedItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
                checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
            }
        }
        console.log(checkedItems);
    }
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" /> {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Below both answers are working well, please checkout any one of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before pushing to items array check whether the item is present already in the selected store. If so, then assign selected as true. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any problem

check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/U3pVM/17424/)

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
        var serverData = ["Nokia", "Htc", "Samsung"];
        var selectedStore = ["Htc"]
        $scope.items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++)
        {
            var modal = {
                name: serverData[i],
                selected: false
            };
            if (selectedStore.indexOf(serverData[i]) >= 0) {
                modal.selected = true;
            }
            $scope.items.push(modal);
        }
        $scope.check = function()
        {
            var checkedItems = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
                    checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                }
            }
            console.log(checkedItems);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`for(var i=0;i<serverData.length;i++)
    {
      var modal = {
      name:serverData[i],
      selected:($scope.Selctedstores !== null && $scope.Selctedstores.indexOf(serverData[i]) > -1) ? true : false
     };`